# Yup context typescript error: Property 'originalValue' does not exist on type 'TestContext<AnyObject>'

Tags: react-hook-form, yup

Yup is causing an Typescript error for not typing context values:

```
   Property 'originalValue' does not exist on type 'TestContext<AnyObject>'.
```

When using yup function test I get a typescript error for originalValue. What should I type context as to remove this error ?

```
.test('00s', 'not a valid number', (value, context) => {
  return context.originalValue.match(ssnRegex)
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround by typecasting context with an extended interface see : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/49512

```js
    interface TestContextExtended {
      originalValue?: unknown;
    }
```

and in your test :

```js
    .test('00s', 'not a valid number', (value, context) => {
      const { originalValue } = context as yup.TestContext & TestContextExtended;
    
      if (typeof originalValue === 'string') {
        return originalValue.match(ssnRegex);
      }
      return false;
    }),
```